# Value is not updating server side events spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm new to spring boot and I'm trying to create a streaming API. But when I change the content of value it doesn't get noticed by the Server Side Events emitter.

```
@RestController
public class SseController {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result;

    //This method only returns a single value. But I want it to return value after every 5 second.
    @GetMapping("/emitter")
    public SseEmitter eventEmitter() {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                //I'm Sending Value To the client Using this method
                emitter.send(result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emitter.completeWithError(e);
            } finally {
                emitter.complete();
            }
        });
        executor.shutdown();
        return emitter;
    }

    //I'm updating value here.
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    private void fetchData() {
        result = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/tickers", String.class);
    }
}
```

I have tried to use thread.sleep() method but after some time it gives me an error async time out.

Comment: SseEmitter is part of the `servlet.mvc` package which means it is highly unlikely it will work with weblux. I would recommend reading the section about `sinks` in the reactor documentation.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem.